# Does THREE.ShaderMaterial create one shader per particle? I'm not sure how it works, If yes, how can I share/update data between each particles shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I would like to create a shader that simulates gravity between 2 particles. For this, each particle must know the position of the other particles, update its position accordingly, and therefore "share" its new position with the other particles.

If I understand correctly, when I do:

```
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
         depthWrite: false,
         blending: AdditiveBlending,
         vertexColors: true,
         vertexShader: galaxyVortexShader,
         fragmentShader: galaxyFragmentShader,
         uniforms: {
             uTime: {value: 0},
             uSize: { value: 10 * renderer.getPixelRatio()},
             uPositions: { value: positionsVec3}
         }
     });
```

I create a shader for each particle ? The problem is that I send the position of all the particles once in "uPositions", but if each particle has its own shader, how can they update their position in the uPositions array to share it to other particles ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is demonstrated in [the official protoplanets demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpgpu_protoplanet). It basically

1. Calculates all `velocities` in a shader that is output as a 64x64 Texture.
2. This Texture gets passed to a second shader that uses it to calculate all `positions`. This way each particle has access to all velocities.
3. Then when rendering the planets onscreen, they all have access to both `velocities` & `positions` textures, so each vertex can access all data for their adjacent vertices. Using 64x64 textures gives you data for 4096 unique particles.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will check it out.
I would like to simulate 1,000,000 particles, do you think it's possible? I'm afraid of being limited by the size of the textures

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. Just make a 1000x1000 texture.

Comment: yeah that working as you can see on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73243084/my-pixels-particles-colors-are-burned-if-camera-is-too-far :D